# Photoshop scripting открыть слой в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Доброго времени!

Есть шаблон для обработки картинок в отдельном файле
В нем есть слой, который можно открыть в отдельной вкладке, вставить картинку, сохранить и она появляется в самом шаблоне, можно экспортировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: можно ли как-то открыть этот слой из скрипта? Я смотрела справочник, но не нашла таких методов у объекта artLayer. Может, я не понимаю чего-нибудь по-английски... Неужели это невозможно?

Comment: В фотошопе консоли никакой нет?

Comment: Текст скрипта опубликуйте тогда, сложно понимать, о чём идёт речь